# How to set default values in Yii2 kartik\tree\TreeViewInput

Tags: php, yii2

I used [kartik\tree\TreeViewInput](http://demos.krajee.com/tree-manager-demo/tree-view-input) in my project but in update form I can't display current selected values in treeview input!

I tried some thing like this based on documentation:

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'tags')->widget(\kartik\tree\TreeViewInput::className(),[
                                                    'name' => 'tags',
                                                    'query' => Tags::find()->addOrderBy('root, lft'),
                                                    'value' => 1,
                                                    'headingOptions' => ['label' => 'tags'],
                                                    'rootOptions' => ['label'=>'<i class="fa fa-building"></i>'],
                                                    'fontAwesome' => true,
                                                    'asDropdown' => true,
                                                    'multiple' => true,
                                                    'options' => ['disabled' => false]
                                                ]);   ?>
```

But it doesn't display tag with (id='1')! How should I display values?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 'displayValue' => 1,
```

to auto display a node with id = 1 on the form.

If you do not want any node to be auto displayed use:

```
'displayValue' => 0,
```

Comment: I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632209/yii2-show-hide-kartik-treeview-nodes) related to treeview can you please see it?